# Python requests response encoded in utf-8 but cannot be decoded

Tags: python, post, request, facebook-messenger

I am trying to scrape my messenger.com (facebook messenger) chats using python and i have used google chromes developer tools to see the POST request for the chat history and i have copied the entire header and body into a format that requests can use.

I get HTTP code 200 implying the request at least got *something* but and i can `print res.encoding` to get the encoding it returned in which it says is utf-8. But i cannot decode it!

here is the function:

```
def download_thread(self, limit, offset, message_timestamp):
    """Download the specified number of messages from the
    provided thread, with an optional offset
    """
    data = request_data(self.thread, offset=offset,
                        limit=limit, group=self.group,
                        timestamp=message_timestamp)

    res = self.ses.post(url_thread, data=data, headers=headers)

    print(res.content)

    thread_contents = json.loads(res.content)
    print(thread_contents)
    return thread_contents
```

yields

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

when it attempts to `json.load` (or `loads`) the data

But `res.encoding` does return utf-8.

I tried unzipping with gzip but that says it is is not gzipped content.

If i just try to do `print(res.content)` i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 200, in <module>
    main()
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 134, in main
    fbms.run()
0f\x82\x048\xbb\xb9=\x87\xebK0.\xff\x90\xdd\xeb\xfa\x16\xc6\xbbz\x8b\x82)\xe8\xaaV\x01^\xda\x8b\xbd\x15d-\xb1\x10@\x17\\\xd43\xa8\x92w\xe8\xc0\xcdU\xc4\xff\xc7\xfa\x90\xb2\xb3\xf5\x84\x11u\x0b\t\x8f\x83r\xf3}\xe5!y$\xe6\xf6c0\xf0\xb4\x98\xcat_\x0c\x08\xb5\xdd\x8ctx\x91\xa9\x95\rB%\xe2\x93\xa52\x85_\xa6\x10\xc2\xc9\xa3\xee4SDb\xa5\x18QJ\x83X\x19)\xaa$\xf4\xb4\xb7\x0b\x84\x15&\x88\x08L\xc9iP\xa2\xb9\xf2\xaf\x96\x96N\xd8\xcf=\x05\xc1\x18\x8d\xa0\xf2Y\x8e\n\xcf\xc8\x0fE4\xd6)\xa1\xd4\xb7D\xd6{i\xc8P\x96R\x11HC\xac\xbcKyT#~}\x93\xf7@K\xc7r/\x82\xb0\xe4\xefX\xf9j\x08\xa6Hp\xfcn\x06\xfdo\x9a\xd0wJ\xb4fJ(\x89+\x1c\xf6\x0eOI\x90\xac\x9eDD\xfd,\xa5\xe9\x89\x1blh\x86Z\x98\x05\xdd9\xc7\xf4\x80\xfcY\x8e\xad\xee\x99!\x15\x13+\x9b\x07\xe8Fdj\xfc\x11\xfc\xfe7\x06h\x02\x00@>]W\x92\xc9\x02\xb1c3\x82\xcd\xa4\xefN9\x90\xe6\x81y\x9c\x84er\xd4\xc3\x06\x1c\x06\x14\xcf\xc7\x07hj\xbfH\xdc\xf5~\xf7z\x18Ce\xaf^\x8c\xab \xdfV\xce\xb8\x11\xf8\x06\x03'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 200, in <module>
    main()
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 134, in main
    fbms.run()
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 43, in run
    thread_contents = self.download_thread(limit, offset, message_timestamp)
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 74, in download_thread
    thread_contents = json.loads(res.content)
  File "/Users/silman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 349, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

oddly printing the content in the middle of the traceback leading me to think there are some invisible characters pushing it down.

I am unable to get the response loaded into a json format because no matter how i handle the response content it isn't properly formatted for json library to interpret.

Moreover if i just do `print(res.text)` i get garbage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 200, in <module>
    main()
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 134, in main
    fbms.run()
}sP���c���f�u0���\� QZed�C��� M$x�Ҹ�H�����eǘ�]���5���^�*�ӄaM�Y��b���/ڶ�JW/���>H6z�\��l4����t=i��%Ҳu�x��%�x�
       F    <���{1i�#%;�rɲ=Rχm��1B�Z(+�(S-���#��\v�{b��
                                                           �    f/V�i̴��_��83�  �_����*��O��
                                                                                            ������Z��i-�TVeaG54�!v�a?ǯ|gu-g��.���"J$�L`&�tΊ#s)�H����s���q���^׷0��[)���j�ॽ�T���U���J�ЁwW���!eg�#j ��r��$y���3�4��4.��M�@Kb�AX�SDb�QJ�X)�,���a�   "Sp�h�����sOA0Vé|�������:%�rKdKC���@ M��.�^
�       �g���SWQHӳ.��BӄG�,����@E��������
                                        nras��L�/��ch@>]W���c3�ͤ�N9��y��er����hj�H��~�zCe�^�� �Vθ�

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 200, in <module>
    main()
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 134, in main
    fbms.run()
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 43, in run
    thread_contents = self.download_thread(limit, offset, message_timestamp)
  File "FBChatScraper.py", line 74, in download_thread
    thread_contents = json.loads(res.content)
  File "/Users/silman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 349, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

EDIT:

MWE as best i can, not sure what data from my post request is private so i left some out

using this data

```
url_thread = "https://www.messenger.com/api/graphqlbatch/"


request_data = {
  "batch_name": "MessengerGraphQLThreadFetcher",
  "__user": "<user_id>",
  "__a": "1",
  "__dyn": "<dyn>",
  "__req": "9",
  '__be'      : '-1',
  '__pc'      : 'PHASED:messengerdotcom_pkg',
  "fb_dtsg": "AQFni7TU2nes:AQGSC8FSDqyw",
  "ttstamp": "265817254666710077746711957586581715370521181008510710777",
  "__rev": "3791607",
  "jazoest": "<jazoest>",
  "queries": '<queries>'
  }

headers = {
  "authority": "www.messenger.com",
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/api/graphqlbatch/",
  "scheme": "https",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-length": "754",
  "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "cookie": "<cookies>",
  "origin": "https://www.messenger.com",
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "referer": "https://www.messenger.com/t/<chatID>",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
}
```

You can get all the `<items>` by using chrome developer tools and lookng on the network tab for a POST request to `Request URL: https://www.messenger.com/api/graphqlbatch/`.

Its easy to find if you scroll up to reload old messages while chrome dev tools is recording.

Then put together a simple request with python

```
import requests as rq
import time

ses = rq.Session()
thread = <ID of thread found in URL of messenger.com>

conversation_type = <'thread_fbids' if group chat else 'user_ids'>

data = request_data
data['messages[{}][{}][offset]'.format(conversation_type, thread)] = 0
data['messages[{}][{}][timestamp]'.format(conversation_type, thread)] = int(time.time())
data['messages[{}][{}][limit]'.format(conversation_type, thread)] = 2000

res = ses.post(url_thread, data=data, headers=headers)

print(res.content)
thread_contents = json.loads(res.content)
print(thread_contents)
```

As what my dev tools got back you can see the start of the json [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI6xv.jpg)

Comment: Well, those bytes definitely aren't UTF-8, or even _close_ to it. Without a [mcve] (a sample URL, minimal code to run against it, and ideally what your dev panel in your browser shows as far as how it decoded the result), it's hard to debug much further.

Comment: @abarnert i tried to put togther a MCVE but it will require you to use dev tools to fill in some info for yourself.

Comment: Very helpful. But do you also have the response headers as seen by Chrome and by requests?

Comment: ill add it as seen by chrome and i'll try to access them in my python

Comment: Hold on a sec—you're sending `"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"`. Is it returning [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli)-compressed data? Test just removing `br` from that line.

Comment: i'm not sure if its returning brotli, when i do `print(res.encoding)' it clearly prints `utf-8`

Comment: Brotli isn't an encoding (charset), it's a compression scheme that Google and some other companies are pushing to replace gzip in the future. I'm pretty sure recent Chrome supports it natively, but requests doesn't. You could of course `pip install brotli` and try to decompress manually, but easier to just not accept it in the first place and get back gzip, which you can already handle.

Comment: I think you have it, now it is printing text that is exactly what chrome sees, unfortuantely now json is throwing `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 34280)` but that is a separate issue.

Comment: With `accept-encoding`, the client just advertises all the compression standards it understand; the order doesn't matter, the server just decides which one (if any) to use for its own reasons. The idea is that it can do intelligent load balancing between CPU use vs. bandwidth savings—`compress` takes less CPU than `gzip` but doesn't compress as well, and of course no compression takes even less CPU but even more bandwidth.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is this line in your request headers:

```
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
```

That `br` requests [Brotli compression](https://github.com/google/brotli), a new-ish compression standard (see [RFC 7932](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7932)) that Google is pushing to replace gzip on the web. Chrome is asking for Brotli because recent versions of Chrome understand it natively. You're asking for Brotli because you copied the headers from Chrome. But `requests` doesn't understand Brotli natively.

You can `pip install brotli` and register the decompresser or just call it manually on `res.content`. But a simpler solution is to just remove the `br`:

```
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
```

… and then you should get `gzip`, which you and `requests` already know how to handle.

Comment: thats what i get for blindly copying headers from the dev tools :p, thanks!

Comment: @Taako The reason I noticed the `br` so quickly is that it triggered a memory from years ago of the way I first learned that there were three standard compression algorithms all the browsers knew instead of just the two that my program knew—I blindly copied from the Mozilla dev tools into my code, and got back garbage… :)

Comment: and now i know too, after struggling for about 4 hours and then breaking down and asking StackOverflow :p another painful learning experience

Comment: I just want to say thank you for this too; the `br` header was causing this problem for me too. This was a real time-saver, it would have taken me a long time to get to the bottom of this by myself. Thank you!!