# How to decode this data that I get as reponse to an HTTP POST request

Tags: json, http, encoding

I am getting this as a response to an HTTP POST request. I have used these as part of my request headers, "Accept-Encoding = gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language = en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" and I got these as part of the response headers, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8". The data is

```
b'\x03R\x1b\x00\xc3\xa4\xc3\x97T\xc3\xbd{/\'\xc2\x81\xc3\xa8\xc3\x91,\xc3\xb8\xc3\x86\xc3\xb2\xc2\xads:\xc3\xbec\x11\xc2\xac\xc2\xbf\xc2\x92(u$CR\xc2\x92N\xc3\xbf\xc2\xbf\xc3\xa97K-\x0e\x0b\xc3\x86\xc2\x97~\xc3\xa9\xc2\xa1\x0f=\xc2\x8a\xc2\x83B\xc2\x98\xc3\xbdo6\xc2\xa1\xc2\x966\xc2\x93\xc3\x8cdkh\xc3\x99G\xc3\xbb;\xc3\xb4\xc3\xafv\xc2\xbbp\x14\xc3\x97\xc2\xa4\xc2\xadBq\xc2\x90b\xc2\xbfEb\x1c\x12\x7f\xc3\xb9L\xc3\xaf\xc3\x91N\xc3\xb4\xc2\xab#Fh\xc2\x80\xc3\x88\xc3\xac\xc3\xb8\xc2\xbd{?\xc3\x92\xc3\x8d!\xc2\x9a\xc3\xa5\xc3\xb3I\xc2\x99\xc2\x8f\xc3\xb7K\xc3\x9a\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbd#\r\xc3\xbf\xc2\xa7-\xc2\xaa\xc3\x84&\xc3\xb1\xc2\x9f_\xc3\xa76~I\xc3\x9b>\xc3\xbf5\xc3\x92\xc3\x98\xc2\xae\xc3\xbb\xc2\xb4M\x0f\xc2\x8f\xc2\x87i\x1e\xc2\xbb\xc3\x9d\xc3\x9a\xc3\x96\xc2\xbe\xc3\xbbf\xc2\xa4O\xc2\xa4M*w1\xc3\xb3\xc2\x8e\xc2\xb4I?\xc3\x89a\xc3\xbb6\xc2\xb5\xc3\x9b\xc3\x96\xc3\x95%q\xc3\x9fzS\xc2\xaaY_\xc2\xba:]\xc2\xa4M\xc2\xba\xc2\x99\xc2\x8f\xc2\xb5\x1d\xc2\x87\xc2\xb6$\xc3\xa9\xc2\x98\xc2\x87\xc3\x89\xc3\x9b\xc3\x93&\x1d\xc3\x92\xc3\x99\xc2\x99\xc2\xb6\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa7r\xc3\xa4h\xc3\x83\xc3\xa7\x0b\xc2\xbd^\\\xc3\xae\xc3\xb2\\\xc3\x81a\xc3\xb2\xc3\x8e\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb9\xc2\xa2\xc2\x94\xc3\x85\xc3\xb78y\xc3\x8aiy= qn\xc3\x9a&p\xc2\x83\x1a(\xc3\xb5*U\xc2\xa0U\xc3\xb5\xc3\x84\xc3\x84\xc3\xbe\xc2\xa1_\xc3\xaa\xc3\x81\xc2\x9f\xc3\xb5i{$e\xc3\x83&\txW\xc3\x9a\xc3\xbe\xc2\x90K\xc3\xb0g\xc3\xaf\xc3\x9d\xc2\xbe,\xc3\x83\xc3\xa94\xc2\xa4M\xc3\xba\x06\xc3\xab\xc3\xa5\xc2\xbf\xc3\xb1D\xc3\xbcd\x07Y\xc2\xb5\x0f,i\xc2\x93\xc3\x8e\xc2\xa7\xc2\xb9\xc3\xbfZ\x7f\xc2\x80\xc3\x83\xc3\xb2\x033I\xc3\xbf\xc3\x82\xc2\xb4\xc3\x9f=I\xc2\x9b\xc2\xa4?9Z\xc3\x90\xc3\xbd\xc3\xb4\xc3\xab\xc3\x97/\xc2\xa5\xc2\xbf^\x06\x0ba\n;q\xc3\xb3\xc2\xaf\r \xc2\x85\x0cp\x17)PN!\xc2\x82\xc3\x8coB\n\xc3\xae\xc3\x85\x0b\xc3\x87H \xc2\x85(\n\xc2\x80\xc2\xa5\xc3\xb8\xc3\x81q\xc2\x80\xc2\x90\xc2\x8bx\xc2\x89\xc3\xa2\'\xc2\x88\xc2\x82\xc3\x81\xc3\x94\x1e2\xc2\x87V\x10p\x16\x0e\xc2\x94\x16\xc3\x97\x07\xc2\x91\xc2\x90\xc3\x80Q\xc2\xae\xc2\x8b\x03\xc2\xa1\xc3\x90B \xc2\x853\xc2\x8bA&\x1cvmn\xc2\x87i,\x1f\x07!D\tD\xc2\x88\xc2\x90\xc3\x83"y\x17\x05\xc2\x95\xc2\xab\xc2\x8b\xc2\x9a\xc2\x97$\xc2\xa4\xc2\xae5q\xc3\xa7Z\xc3\xbd\xc3\xaf8\xc2\xa6\x1b\xc2\x81\xc3\x802\xc2\xad\xc2\xa8v\xc3\xbe\xc2\x9az\xc3\x9e\xc3\xb7i\x0b\xc3\xa4\xc3\x85lK\xc3\xbdh\xc2\xb4i\\]\xc2\x9c\xc3\xa0m\xc2\x87C\x7fZ\xc3\x9bx\xc3\xa8\xc3\xabl\x15\x0e\xc2\xa7\xc2\xadI\xc3\xb1\xc3\x8bLN\xc2\x86f\xc2\xa6\xc3\xaeo\xc3\x9au\xc2\x9b\xc3\xad\xc2\x8b\xc3\xa4R^\xc2\x97\x1do\xc2\xb2\xc2\xb5+\xc2\x927\x19\xc2\x83"\x0bJ\xc3\x8a\xc2\x92\xc3\x8c\xc2\xba@\xc3\xbaw\xc3\x8e\xc3\xba\xc2\xafm\xc2\xb1!\xc3\xa46\x0f\xc2\xa4\xc2\x9f\x11\xc2\x92cm\xc3\x85\x04\t\xc2\xa4\xc2\x90A\xc2\x8e\xc3\x84\xc3\x84s\xc3\x89\x0b\x02\xc3\xa3\xc2\x94\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa6G1\xc2\x8a\x17U?\xc2\x86\xc2\xa0\x02\xc2\xae\xc3\xac\xc3\x87-P \xc3\x94x\xc3\x81R%\xc2\x97\xc3\x9f\x1cU\xc3\x83x\xc2\xa9#\xc2\x8dJ\xc2\xbe\x1e\xc2\x88\xc3\xaa\x08?\x0c\xc3\x8c\x1c\x065f\t\xc3\x96\xc3\x85\xc2\x93\xc2\xb8\xc2\x8b\x16\xc3\x8b\xc3\x87\xc2\x8f\x02\xc2\x88\'*iXG\xc2\x9c\xc3\x90\xc2\xb0$\xc2\x8e\xc2\x996\x17\xc2\x80\x0eH\x05\xc2\xa1\xc2\xa3s\xc2\x89\xc2\x88FM\xc3\x8c\xc3\xb5\xc2\xac\x0c-L^c\xc2\xba\x1e\nx`\xc3\xa5\xc3\x97\xc2\x9e\x04\xc2\xa2\xc2\x98}o\xc3\x9b\xc3\xbc-h\xc2\xaa\xc3\x98\x1d\xc3\xa1\rb\xc2\xba\xc3\x96t\xc3\x93y\xc3\xb7p^m\xc3\x8e\x0bo_>~x\rC\xc3\xb5My\xc3\x88\xc2\xa4W>\xc2\xb4\xc3\x8b\xc3\x9dr\xc2\xabN\xc2\xb6Au\xc2\xben\xc3\xb3\xc3\xb1[b\xc3\x95(\xc2\xb5`\x1en\xc3\x9b\xc3\x9a?P\xc3\xabV\xc3\x95&t\xc2\xad\xc2\x9dk\xc2\xbb\xc3\x9a\xc2\xbe\x1a\x1b\xc2\xaa\xc2\xbbXb\xc2\x9d\xc2\xa0\xc3\xb8\xc3\xa2\xc2\xa1|\xc3\x82\xc3\x85\x01$q\xc2\x84 .Df\x00\xc2\xa4$\xc2\xa5\xc2\x92\xc2\xa5_\xc2\xb5\xc3\xb6w\xc3\xa8]\xc2\xb9kS\x05\rUR\xc2\x89\xc3\x90\xc2\xa3\x03\xc3\xab\x1f\xc2\xb2\xc3\xa9vm\xc3\xac\xc3\x9e\xc2\xb6\xc3\xb90-\xc2\x8a\xc3\x99\xc3\x84\xc3\xa3\xc3\x9d\xc2\xbe\xc3\x9b\xc2\xbd}\x1apXn\xc3\xaa\xc2\xb2\xc2\xbe^\xc2\xa71\xc3\xb2\xc2\x83V\x1f\xc2\x8a\xc2\x8c\xc2\x8e\xc2\xaf/\xc3\x89K\x1b\xc3\xb3\xc3\xb5\xc2\xab\xc2\xa9w\xc2\xa4T;&\xc3\x9c>\xc2\xb0kc~\xc2\xb5\xc3\xb3\xc2\x99&\xc2\x9f\xc2\x87R\xc2\x93"\n\xc2\xbc\xc2\xa7\xc3\xa7A}]\x1c<\xc2\x98\xc3\x89I\x00\x1f\xc2\xaa\xc3\x86@AC\xc3\xbc`\xc2\xaf\xc3\x81EAJ\xc3\x8a4\xc3\xb7\xc2\xbf"\xc2\x9acS\x17r#-P\x08\xc2\x82\x02\xc2\x97\x1f\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa2\x1c\xc3\xb7|2\xc3\x99M\xc2\xac\x06\x1f\xc3\x82f.^\xc2\xa2.\xc2\xb5\t\xc2\x88\xc2\x92\xc2\x92\x1aKh\xc3\xbe:\xc2\x89\xc3\x80\xc2\xa9\xc2\xab\xc2\xae#qe\x0c\x119~\xc2\x90=\xc3\x9b\xc3\xb7\xc2\xae\xc2\xbf\xc3\xabf\xc2\x96\x7fD\xc3\x97\xc3\x96\xc3\xae\xc3\xbd\xc3\x98O\xc3\xa3\xc3\x9a\xc2\x86\xc2\x92\xc2\xaf\xc3\x9d\xc3\xad\xc3\x9f\xc3\xbd\xc3\x99\xc2\xbd\x7f\xc3\xb7\xc3\xb4\xc3\xbd\xc2\xbb3;\x17=>|t:\xc3\x8fc\x7f\xc2\x97\xc2\xbfM\xc3\xb3\xc2\x97\xc3\x9c\xc3\x96<eid\xc3\xad\xc2\x92\xc3\x88\xc3\x82b\xc2\xa8\xc2\xa1f/\xc2\xafm\x1b\xc2\xa6\xc2\x92\xc2\xa1\xc3\x8b\xc2\xa1CmW;\xc3\x976j\xc3\xb8BA\x16\x13b\xc2\xbd=\x12\xc2\x8aB\xc2\xb1\x11\xc2\x85\xc3\xa4j\xc3\x9bfm\xc2\xbeI\x04_\xc3\xb5b:\xc3\xb5\xc3\xb3\xc3\x94\xc3\x86\x11\xc3\xbdc/^\xc3\xae\xc2\x95\xc2\x8ff\xc3\x8d\xc3\xaf\xc3\x8bCzM\xc2\x95B\xc2\x95{\xc3\x90?\xc3\xa3\xc2\x93yR;\xc3\x97j\xc2\x9b`\xc2\xad\xc3\xb7\xc3\xb0UU<\xc2\x9b\xc3\x98\xc3\xbf\xc2\x8f\xc3\xab\xc2\xb6\xc3\xac5\xc3\x82\xc3\xa8\x0f$\x0fU\xc3\x8d\xc3\xa2\xc2\xbd\xc2\xaf\x08.L0\x1d\x05k\xc3\xa3\xc3\x8a\xc2\xbc\x0cM\xc2\x8b!\xc2\x96\xc3\xbd\xc2\xbe\xc2\xac\xc2\xb4i\x1ac\xc2\x84\x18\xc3\xb5\r\xc2\x98\x14\x15^qw\xc2\xa3\xc2\x91\x07\x16\xc2\xb0\xc2\x84\xc2\xae\xc2\xbf\xc2\x8dr\x06%\xc2\xac\xc3\x8cU\xc2\xb0[\xc3\x8a\xc2\x98|Z\xc3\xbeG/\xc2\x8f\xc3\x87a\xc2\x9c\xc2\x86y\xc2\xa8|\x02\xc2\xbc\x0cA\xc2\x9d\xc3\x93\xc3\x96U`\xc2\x86\r\xc3\xb0\xc3\xa7\x7f\x7f9L\xc3\x9d\xc3\xaf\xc3\xbdr\xc3\xac\xc2\xbf\xc2\xb5q\x18\x1b\xc3\xbb\xc3\xbd\xc3\xaf\x17M\xc2\x97\xc3\x83\xc2\x94\xc3\xaf\xc2\x92\xc3\x86\xc2\x8e`Q\xc2\x8aa\xc2\x94\xc3\x86FC\xc3\x8c\xc2\x8a\xc2\xb2R\xc2\x95\xc3\x89\xc3\x87H\xc2\x92)"5\xc3\x89r\xc2\x9cp\xc2\xa2\x0e\x0cA\\\x18b\xc2\x841&\xc2\x98b\xc2\x869\x14\xc3\x9e\xc2\xbc`\xc2\x80!F\x18c\xc2\x82)f\xc2\x98\xc3\x9b\xc3\x89\x15\x0b,\xc2\xb0\xc3\x80\x02\x0b,\xc2\xb0\xc3\x80\x02\x0b(b\'F#\t\x03\x0c1\xc3\x82\x18\x13L1\xc3\x83\xc3\x9c\xc2\x8e0\xc3\x80\x00\x03\x0c0\xc3\x80\x00\x03\x0c0\xc3\x80`T0)G\xc2\xa5\xc2\xa1Y\xc3\x9d\xc3\x8a$"\xc3\x83,\xc3\xba\xc3\xbf\xc2\x8d\xc2\xb7a\\\xc2\xbbW\xc3\x93\xc3\x92\xc2\x9f.\xc3\xbf\xc2\xb9)\x05m\xc3\xb1W\xc3\x86\xc3\x9e\xc2\xbd\xc2\xaa\xc3\x95ru\xc3\xa3\xc2\xaf\xc3\x8a\xc3\x9d[\xc3\xb7\xc3\xa5\xc2\xab\xc2\xbc\x13rPd\xc3\x85:\xc3\xa5;\xc2\xb6l\xc3\x87\x19\xc2\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\xad\xc2\x89*\xc2\xa2\xc3\xb5\xc3\x94\xc2\xaa\xc3\x80rS\xc3\xb7\xc2\x85\xc3\x88\x04\xc2\xbd\xc3\xb7\xc3\xaa\\Y\x11\xc2\x9a\xc2\xa6!/\x16\xc3\x9e\xc2\xb6\xc2\xa1C\xc3\x80\xc3\x80\xc3\xbd\x00y\xc2\xa92f15db\xc3\xac\x1d\xc3\x92\xc3\xa0\xc2\x87\x0b\x14\x01G\xc3\xb5!\xc3\x82\xc3\xa4GK(\xc3\x84B\xc2\x86\xc3\x88Q\xc2\x96I5|yW\xc2\xa3XK\x15\x05/.\x06\x0b\xc2\x9e:<`\xc3\x8cG Bb\xc2\xb3\xc2\x98\xc2\xa3\xc3\x87\xc3\x95\t\xc3\x94e\xc3\x9a\xc2\xa3\xc2\x86\x141\x7f)wD\xc3\x90\xc3\xa7\xc2\xa2<=v\x1f\xc3\x9a2\xc3\x9d\xc2\xbb?\xc3\xbbz0\xc2\xa4\xc2\xbd\xc3\x91\xc3\x8d\xc3\x9a\xc2\x9f\x1e\xc2\x94v\xc3\x93\xc2\x8c\xc2\xa4\xc3\x9c\xc3\x86z"\xc3\xb7\xc3\x87|\xc3\x8a\xc3\x84t.\xc2\xb2\xc3\xa2>q\xc3\x87\xc2\xb3vO\xc2\xa9t\xc2\xbbu\xc2\x8e\xc2\xbf)\xc3\xb0\xc2\xbe\xc2\x90L\xc3\x93\x1d}}\xc2\x99\xc2\xaa\xc2\xb6\xc2\xb9v\xc2\x9d\t\x02\x08!\xc2\x82\x18\x12\xc2\xbb\xc2\xa6B\x069\x12,(\xc2\x80\x00B\x1bi\xc2\xba\xc2\xb0[MY\x1c\xc2\x8du\xc2\x91\x12\xc3\xb2r\x11\xc2\xa4>a\tq\xc3\xb9Q`\x12QP\xc2\x9e\xc2\x8b\xc3\x90\xc3\xac\xc3\x94\xc2\x8b\'@\xc2\xa9\xc2\xb4\xc2\xa4T\xc2\xae\xc2\x82,/\n\xc3\xa2\xc3\xa4$\x17\xc2\x96\xc3\x88ED\xc2\x898\xc3\x81\xc3\xbd[H\xc2\x80\x15J%\xc2\x9a\xc3\xa8\x10\x1e\x1a@\x07;\xc3\x92\x00yRb\xc2\x98\xc2\x92\x0bB\x19\xc2\xbf\xc3\xaa\xc2\x83\x00f$B\x1a\x02b.\xc2\x86\x05m4 \x07/n"\x14,\xc2\xa2\xc2\x88\x1c\xc2\x97\x16s\x08\xc2\x8dF\xc2\x8e\xc3\x92\x089\x111\xc3\x92\xc3\x84XV\x1f\xc3\xa4\xc3\x82\x00\x0e\xc3\xa9\xc2\x85#h\xc2\x9d\xc3\xaa\xc2\x83\xc3\x82\xc2\xac\xc3\x841\xc3\x8b\xc3\x87\xc3\x89X\xc2\x91\xc3\x8a\xc2\xa5V\x02\xc2\xab\xc2\x928\xc3\x8e\xc2\xa3]\xc2\x8e\xc3\x928U\xc3\x83O\x08\xc2\xa8\xc2\xa8Q\xc2\x94\xc3\x9eK\xc3\x8a\xc3\xa5\xc3\x9cF\xc2\x88\xc3\xa3\xc2\xbf\xc2\x86l){\xc3\x81\xc3\xba\x1b?\xc3\xa0\xc2\x89\x07\x0b\xc3\xbe\xc2\xa9\x1d\xc2\x8fM\xc3\x87\xc3\xae\x10\xc2\x8dy\xc3\xa8\xc2\xbc\xc3\xadq;q\xc2\xab\xc3\xb1\xc2\xb3\xc3\x8cdS;.\xc3\x91\xc3\x84o\xc2\xb8\xc2\x91\xc3\x85\xc3\xb4\xc3\x8dkBQtP\xc3\x85arr\xc3\xbb\xc2\x91\xc3\xbf\xc2\xb0\xc2\xb6\xc3\x9b+/\xc2\xbb\xc3\x8f\xc3\x83n\x06C^vG\x14\x17\x06\x08V\x15\xc2\x8e\xc2\xb0Dbq\xc3\x923\xc2\x86\xc2\xa2\xc3\x9b\xc3\xa3\xc2\x97\xc3\xa9\xc2\xbe\x1dC\xc2\xbc\xc3\xa5\xc3\xb7~Y\xc2\xbb\xc3\x9f\xc2\x86\xc3\xb9b\xc3\x983\xc2\xa6FM\xc3\x8a~F\x19?\xc2\x85j\x13\xc2\xb7j\xc2\xb9\xc3\xbe\xc2\xb7=\xc2\x8f\xc3\xbaV\xc2\xbd\xc3\x9bi\xc2\xa0Sw\xc3\xbd\xc2\xb2\xc3\xa6\xc3\xa3p\xc3\x9a2\xc2\x93\xc3\xbc!6\xc3\xb5\xc2\xb9\xc2\x98\xc2\xae\xc3\xbby\x1f=\xc3\x95\xc2\xb9K\xc3\x96tx\xc3\xb5\xc3\x9bLL\xc3\x95\xc3\x99\x00\xc3\x88\x7f\x00@\xc2\xbc\xc3\x81\xc3\xa6-\x11\xc3\x8c\xc2\xba\x10\xc3\x9e\xc3\x8b\x16\x0cfJ\xc2\x9a\x7f)x\xc2\x8d\xc2\x9a\xc2\xbbK\xc3\xa5o\xc2\xa9\xc2\xb3\x18\xc2\x8c\x10T\xc2\xa7\xc2\xaa\xc3\xac\xc2\x9c\xc3\xbdQ6\xc2\x84\x0cz</U\xc3\xac\xc2\xb6\xc3\xbf\xc2\x99\xc3\x93\x1b\t\xc3\xb5y\xc3\xb0>\xc3\x8e\xc3\xb5\xc2\x87\xc3\x8c\xc3\x8f\xc3\xb5\xc2\x8b\xc3\xb0\xc3\x81\'\xc2\x92\xc3\xa8E\xc3\x8eUT\xc3\x92\xc2\xb9\xc2\x8f\x18)Z\x11D\'b\xc2\xa27+P\xc2\x9b\xc2\xba\xc2\xa1\xc3\x9dC\xc2\x90\xc2\xb2\xc2\x80\x10R\xc2\x95\xc3\x97t,\xc3\x9a\xc2\x98~\r1\xc2\x9f\xc2\x85\xc3\x83\xc2\x82\x00&\x18:\xc3\xaaQR\xc3\xa7/K\x0bI\xc3\x8bC\xc2\x98kKYRXg2\xc2\xb6:Oa\xc3\xb2\xc2\x99^\xc3\x8b\x0e0\xc2\xbd\x10\x1bJ\xc2\x89^\xc3\x85\xc3\x8d\xc2\xb5\xc2\x87"RI\x18b5a\xc3\x90\xc2\x91\xc3\x89\xc3\x96\xc2\xb6\xc2\x93S\x12%\xc3\x90$M\xc3\x8a\xc2\x98\xc2\xb6\xc3\xb2gj*\xc2\x951u\xc3\x84\x06`\xc2\xba3q\xc2\xa3;\xc3\xa5\xc3\x80\xc2\x9cvS\xc2\xbd\x16\xc3\x9f\xc3\xb7\xc3\x80;&H\xc2\xb6\xc3\xac\xc2\xbe\xc2\x91[\x03\xc2\x8a\xc2\x8c\xc2\xb9\xc2\xa4\xc2\x95\xc3\xb8\xc3\x93\x17\xc2\xae_W\xc2\xa4\xc3\x92<b*"\xc2\xb5^;\xc2\x90\xc2\xac1W\xc3\x94/B"7z\' \xc2\x97d\xc3\xa1\x14\xc3\x91J\xc3\xa6H\xc2\xb9P\x0e*\xc2\x91\xc3\x92\x15\x19\xc2\x8d\xc2\xa8\x00\xc2\xab\xc3\xbf-\xc3\xa0\xc2\x8fH|\xc2\xb5\n\x0e^\xc3\x8cIQ\xc2\xa8kI\x08\xc2\xad\xc2\xae\x03\xc3\x8aLd\x08\xc2\x9d\xc2\xa9\xc2\x80\xc3\x96\xc3\x9d\x16h\xc3\xa6\xc3\x83d\xc2\xa5\xc2\x96\xc3\xbeM\x10\xc2\xa0\xc2\xbajh\xc3\xa4\xc2\xbc\x03\x07B8\x10\xc3\xbb1\x0e\xc2\xa6\xc3\x8c\xc2\xa7\xc3\xb3\xc2\xb3\xc3\x85\xc3\xb4\xc3\xa1\xc3\x98\x00*\x01\xc3\xba~uh$M`\xc3\xb2P\xc2\xb5c:X\xc2\xa5O\xc3\x99\xc2\xb2\xc2\x9asHif\xc3\x85\x15+\xc2\x99\xc2\x80\xc3\x8a\xc2\x8e\r\xc2\x95o1\xc2\x94}R\x0b\x1dIm\xc3\xadf\xc3\xackOe\xc3\x9e\xc2\x981\x00\xc3\xb8\x7f\x01@\xc3\x94\xc3\x9a\xc3\xab\xc2\x87h\x00\xc3\xb93k\xc3\x99\xc2\x92\xc2\xbd\xc3\xb8P\xc2\xad(\xc2\xbd\xc2\xbc$W\xc3\xa0\xc3\xb9oo\xc3\x8e\xc3\x86EFF\xc3\x98(\xc2\x91\xc2\x9bB\xc3\xa9\x1f\xc3\x85\x1a\xc2\xbf\x0c\xc2\xa5T\xc2\x85R\xc3\xafM\xc3\x9b2g\xc2\x962\x0c}(\xc3\x8d\xc2\x95\xc3\xa6\x10\xc3\x9e\xc3\xac\x17\xc2\x8e\x13\xc3\xa1\x10\x12\xc2\xa8\x18\xc3\x8e:}\xc3\xb5C#\x10d\xc3\xb3\xc2\xb1;\xc2\x98\xc2\x9fNa\xc2\xa6\xc2\x9d\xc3\xbe\xc3\x97\xc3\xa9_z\xc3\x9b.Fy\x1ff\xc3\x8a\xc2\x87\xc3\xbb\x0b\'\x17\xc3\x91\xc2\x998\xc2\x857\nD\xc2\x9c\xc3\x83\xc3\x98\xc2\x82Y\x17w\xc2\x8d\xc3\xa8\xc2\x81\x02\xc3\xae\x1d\xc2\x9a2ro7\x1ad\x08\xc3\x88Q\xc2\xac\xc2\x9e-PKI\x0b\rw-j\xc3\x8c\xc3\x8f\xc2\xb2P\x03QV5\xc2\x8a\xc3\xbchJ\x18]\x02\xc3\x95\xc2\x85\xc3\x9e\xc2\xaa\xc3\x8as\xc2\xb5\xc3\x863Oj\xc2\xbae\xc2\xbc\xc2\x91\xc2\xa3\xc3\x8b\xc2\xa9\xc2\x9b.j=\'ck\x14\xc3\xab\xc2\x82\xc3\xb0\xc3\xa8\xc2\xa1\xc2\x95\xc2\xa4MaC\x13\x14\xc3\x9bA\xc2\x80\xc3\x96?\x05\xc3\x91\xc2\x88\xc3\x87\xc2\x91\xc2\x94"h\xc2\xab\xc3\xbe\x12\x04\x08r|\xc3\x83\x1fR\xc3\x83\x1e\xc3\x9b2\xc3\xadxM]\xc2\xbbDFM\xc2\xa5?\xc2\x9f\xc2\xa2VENnU\xc2\x9f\xc2\x844\xc2\xa7&,\xc3\x85\xc2\x9fRA#Ky\xc3\xb2)\xc2\xbd\xc3\x89y\x1c+b\xc2\x95\xc3\xbc\xc2\xb3\xc3\x91\xc3\xad"/\xc2\xbb\x1d\xc2\x8e\xc3\xba\xc3\xb2\xc3\xb3\xc3\xa7\xc3\x83\xc3\xa38{\x0c\xc3\xb7\xc2\xae\xc2\xa2\xc3\xbe\xc2\x98\xc2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here: [Python requests response encoded in utf-8 but cannot be decoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702214/python-requests-response-encoded-in-utf-8-but-cannot-be-decoded)

The problem is this line in your request headers:

`"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",` 
That br requests Brotli compression, a new-ish compression standard (see RFC 7932) that Google is pushing to replace gzip on the web. Chrome is asking for Brotli because recent versions of Chrome understand it natively. You're asking for Brotli because you copied the headers from Chrome. But requests doesn't understand Brotli natively.

You can pip install brotli and register the decompresser or just call it manually on res.content. But a simpler solution is to just remove the br:

`"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"`,
… and then you should get gzip, which you and requests already know how to handle.